# How to export FBX three.js format file

Tags: json, three.js, fbx

How to export FBX three.js format file?

I found references on the internet showing how an FBX file is converted to three.js, but I can't find how a JSON three.js file is converted to FBX files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there are no exporters for the .FBX file format from a three.js json scene format.  You can export to stl or [obj](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_exporter_obj).  To see some examples of exporters, take a look at the examples in the dev branch.  There you can find a folder for exporters: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/exporters

At the moment, there is a pull request to add [FBX loading](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7869), but no exporting.

Edit: For completion, a few more links:

- [FBX SDK Python](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_724D83D7_02E2_4BD0_8610_9EF516508FD3_htm) - Might be helpful in case you want to learn about what is possible with the python bindings for fbx
- [Three.js Converters](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx) - Discusses a python conversion tool to the Three.js format.  Might be able to reverse engineer this tool to convert Three.js to FBX.

Comment: There is now an FBX ➡️ THREE.js JSON converter, with some limits on features supported (no animation, only certain materials...). https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/converters/fbx

Comment: At the time of writing, this was not the case.