# How to export rigged character from Maya to Three.js

Tags: three.js, maya, fbx

I have a rigged character setup with Human IK in Maya 2017. How to I export this for Three.js as a skinned mesh/skeleton so I can pose and apply animations to that object through javascript?

Comment: you can export FBX and follow this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487237/how-to-export-fbx-three-js-format-file

Comment: That post doesn't cover exporting rigged characters